# Powershell sort two fields and and get latest from CSV

Tags: powershell, sorting, unique

I am trying to find a way to sort a CSV by two fields and retrieve only the latest item.

CSV fields: time, computer, type, domain.

Item that works is below but is slow due to scale of CSV and I feel like there is a better way.

```
$sorted = $csv | Group-Object {$_.computer} | ForEach {$_.Group | Sort-Object Time -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}
```

Comment: with a large-ish CSV file, you may find it better to use `Get-Content` and build a hashtable based on the `Computer` column. that would use less RAM, sidestep building a more-complex object for each row, and get everything grouped - all in one fell swoop. ///// if it is a REALLY huge file, then take a look at the StreamReader stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee_Dailey suggests, you'll probably have better luck with a `hashtable` instead, `Group-Object` (unless used with the `-NoElement` parameter) is fairly slow and memory-hungry.

The *fastest way* off the top of my head would be something like this:

```
# use the call operator & instead of ForEach-Object to avoid overhead from pipeline parameter binding
$csv |&{
  begin{
    # create a hashtable to hold the newest object per computer 
    $newest = @{}
  }
  process{
    # test if the object in the pipeline is newer that the one we have
    if(-not $newest.ContainsKey($_.Computer) -or $newest[$_.Computer].Time -lt $_.Time){
      # update our hashtable with the newest object
      $newest[$_.Computer] = $_
    }
  }
  end{
    # return the newest-per-computer object
    $newest.Values
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is very helpful and lead me down the hashtable road.  So far this seems much more efficient.